# Nunit multi-browser execution in a data-driven framework

Tags: selenium, nunit

```
class SurfaceMinMax
        {
     [Test TestCaseSource(typeof(ExcelDataParser),"SurfaceData")]
            public void RechercherSurface(string min, string max)
            {
            }
        }
```

I'm using TestCaseSource to run my tests using several sets of data from an excel file.

How do i run the tests in a multiple browsers/versions?

Using a set of [TestFixture (typeof(a browser type))] on a class level will not solve my problem because i need to run my tests with different browsers and versions.

I need to set the driver manually via coding an not automatically from the [TestFixture] which will take the installed browser version only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NUnit TestFixtures are ignorant of browser types. They work for browsers because your code uses the browser type to select the browser. You should be able to create a TestFixture that takes whatever arguments you would need to "manually" select the browser and just put that "manual" code in your OneTimeSetUp method.

I don't know how you want to write code to initialize the browser "manually" since you haven't said in your question. So, to give an example, I'll pretend you need a string representing the browser, a version and a magic int.

You would then use...

```
[TestFixture("firefox", "42.0", 12345)]
public class MyFixture
{
    public MyFixture(string browser, string version, int magic)
    {
        // Save the args in member fields or properties
    }

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public MyOneTimeSetUp()
    {
        // Use the saved values to initialize the browser of choice
    }

    // Continue with whatever you already do in the fixture
}
```

Hope that makes it clear. I can edit this if you provide more info about the actual args you need to have in order to initialize the browser.

Comment: Do you mean implementing another TestFixture class? the idea is to use something like [TestFixture ("chrome")] and [TestFixture("firefox")] and then in the [SetUp] initialize the driver depending on the value "chrome" or "firefox".